# Pivoting on multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have the following computed data

```
Pl_Name      Cnt       Status       Level

CF            21       Active         2

CF            3        Closed         2

INFRA         1        Closed         3

OTHER         40       Active         2

OTHER         4        Active         3

OTHER         2        Closed         1

OTHER         9        Closed         2

OTHER         5        Closed         3

MSG           5        Active         2
```

The query used for above result was

```
SELECT Platforms.PlatformName,COUNT(Ticket.TicketId) AS Count,Ticket.TicketStatus,Ticket.Priority
FROM Platforms
INNER JOIN Ticket
ON Platforms.ID = Ticket.Platform_id
GROUP BY Platforms.PlatformName,Ticket.TicketStatus,Ticket.Priority
```

Now I Need the following result from above result

```
              Level1              Level2             Level3

PL_Name  Active    Closed    Active    Closed    Active    Closed

CF         0         0         21        3         0         0

INFRA      0         0         0         0         0         1

OTHER      0         2         40        5         4         5

MSG        0         0         2         0         0         0
```

Comment: SQL Server is a RDBMS for storing data and retrieving data, your data presentation requirement should be dealt with an appropriate reporting tool like SSRS or Crystal Reports etc. I know for a fact this can be done ins SSRS very easily.

Answer (score 0):

Try this .. You need to use `pivot` to transpose your rows to columns.

```
SELECT Pl_Name,
       Isnull([Level1_active], 0)[Level1_active],
       Isnull([Level1_closed], 0)[Level1_closed],
       Isnull([Level2_active], 0)[Level2_active],
       Isnull([Level2_closed], 0)[Level2_closed],
       Isnull([Level3_active], 0)[Level3_active],
       Isnull([Level3_closed], 0)[Level3_closed]
FROM  (SELECT Pl_Name,
              cnt,
              'Level' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), level) + '_'
              + status piv_col
       FROM   Computeddata) a
      PIVOT (Max(cnt)
            FOR piv_col IN([Level1_active],
                           [Level1_closed],
                           [Level2_active],
                           [Level2_closed],
                           [Level3_active],
                           [Level3_closed])) piv
```

**Note:** Result is some what similar to your result column headers might be same as you expect

Comment: Thanks, but all the values are coming as 0. i changed MAX(cnt) to COUNT(cnt) and SUM(cnt) but still the same result. 0 in all the places. My Computedata table still has all the values.

Comment: After few alterations from my computedata table, it worked..thanks a lot :)